# How do I enable CORS in my serverless typescript lambda function?

Tags: typescript, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless

When I try to make a POST request to my lambda function, I get this error back:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'XXX" from origin 'http://localhost:3001' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I'm not gonna lie, I don't really understand server stuff all that well. However, this is what my `serverless.ts` looks like:

```
import type { AWS } from '@serverless/typescript';

import generateSignature from '@functions/generateSignature';

const serverlessConfiguration: AWS = {
  service: 'generate-signature',
  frameworkVersion: '3',
  plugins: ['serverless-esbuild', 'serverless-offline'],
  useDotenv: true,
  provider: {
    name: 'aws',
    runtime: 'nodejs14.x',
    apiGateway: {
      minimumCompressionSize: 1024,
      shouldStartNameWithService: true,
    },
    environment: {
      AWS_NODEJS_CONNECTION_REUSE_ENABLED: '1',
      NODE_OPTIONS: '--enable-source-maps --stack-trace-limit=1000',
      X_KEY: '${env:X_KEY}',
      Y_SECRET: '${env:Y_SECRET}',
    },
  },
  // import the function via paths
  functions: { generateSignature },
  package: { individually: true },
  custom: {
    esbuild: {
      bundle: true,
      minify: false,
      sourcemap: true,
      exclude: ['aws-sdk'],
      target: 'node14',
      define: { 'require.resolve': undefined },
      platform: 'node',
      concurrency: 10,
    },
  },
};

module.exports = serverlessConfiguration;
```

What I've tried to do was enable cors in `generateSignature/index.ts`:

```
import schema from './schema';
import { handlerPath } from '@libs/handler-resolver';

export default {
  handler: `${handlerPath(__dirname)}/handler.main`,
  events: [
    {
      http: {
        method: 'post',
        path: 'generateSignature',
        cors: true, // <--- enabled here?
        request: {
          schemas: {
            'application/json': schema,
          },
        },
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

But that didn't seem to work. Then I tried to return the headers in my response to the client:

```
export const formatJSONResponse = (response: Record<string, unknown>) => {
  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    headers: {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true,
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(response)
  }
```

But that didn't work either. What am I missing?

EDIT: Adding my actual function:
`generateSignature.ts`

```
import type { ValidatedEventAPIGatewayProxyEvent } from '@libs/api-gateway';
import { formatJSONResponse } from '@libs/api-gateway';
import { middyfy } from '@libs/lambda';
import KJUR from 'jsrsasign';

import schema from './schema';

const generateSignature: ValidatedEventAPIGatewayProxyEvent<typeof schema> = async (event: any) => {
  try {
    const iat = Math.round((new Date().getTime() - 30000) / 1000);
    const exp = iat + 60 * 60 * 2;

    const oHeader = { alg: 'HS256', typ: 'JWT' };

    const oPayload = {
      sdkKey: process.env.X_KEY,
      appKey: process.env.X_KEY,
      mn: event.meetingNumber,
      role: event.role,
      iat,
      exp,
      tokenExp: iat + 60 * 60 * 2,
    };

    const sHeader = JSON.stringify(oHeader);
    const sPayload = JSON.stringify(oPayload);
    const signature = KJUR.jws.JWS.sign(
      'HS256',
      sHeader,
      sPayload,
      process.env.Y_SECRET
    );

    return formatJSONResponse({
      event,
      signature,
    })
  } catch (error) {
    return formatJSONResponse({
      error,
    })
  }
};

export const main = middyfy(generateSignature);
```

and this is `middyfy` (which came with the typescript template I used). I added `@middy/http-cors` myself.

```
import middy from "@middy/core"
import middyJsonBodyParser from "@middy/http-json-body-parser"
import cors from "@middy/http-cors"

export const middyfy = (handler) => {
  return middy(handler).use(middyJsonBodyParser()).use(cors())
}
```

Comment: Have you configured a Function Url for the Lambda?

Comment: @RossBush yes I have. Let me add a few more examples

Comment: You may also want to specify -> "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "OPTIONS,POST,GET" in your response.

Comment: If you have created a Function Url and you are using the console then there is a configure CORS section you may want to look that over.

Comment: @RossBush added a bit more info